# Extracts tweets from a specific twitter use

Tags: scala, twitter, twitter4j

I want to extracts tweets from a specific user using scala. My code is given below:

```
import twitter4j._
import twitter4j.Status
import collection.JavaConversions._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark._

val CONSUMER_KEY = "hidden"
val CONSUMER_SECRET = "hidden"
val ACCESS_TOKEN = "hidden"
val ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "hidden"

System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", CONSUMER_KEY)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", CONSUMER_SECRET)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", ACCESS_TOKEN)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

val twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance
val statuses = twitter.search(new Query("aTwitterUser")).getTweets

statuses.foreach(status => println(status.getText + "\n"))
```

By using the above code I am able to get all tweets in with specified user is mentioned plus tweets of user. That did not resolve my problem. I only want to print tweets made by user. Any help will be appreciated.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

See point 4 on http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Use the 'source:' query

java code:

```
 // The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.
    Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j yusukey");
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
        System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
    }
```

more query operators on: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

special attention to 'from:' operator:

```
    Query query = new Query("from:twitter4j yusukey");
```

Comment: I translated your code as:statuses.  foreach(status=> println(status.getUser().getScreenName+":" +status.getText)) but again the output is same. It is displaying tweets from other users too.

Comment: No. How to use from operator. Any example please.

Comment: have a look now. edited, by adding the example at the end. just replace the query in the full example by the last one

Comment: I replace "yusukey" with twitter user but result is null